# <ION-ITEM> with background color

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am looking for a way to generate a list with *ngFor where each  generated would have 1 of 3 possible background colors.  I have the following in my .ts file:

```
this.items = [
  {id:'00001', status:'pending', title: 'hi1', description: 'test1'},
  {id:'00002', status:'pending', title: 'hi2', description: 'test2'},
  {id:'00003', status:'pending', title: 'hi3', description: 'test3'}
];
```

and I have this in my .html file:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="viewItem(item)" ng-style="{'background-color': {{item.status}}}">{{item.title}}</ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

and I added to the $colors in my variables.svss file.  The file now looks like this:

```
$colors: (
  primary:    #488aff,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222,
  pending:    #FFFF99,
  complete:   #9966ff,
  overdue:    #ff0000
);
```

So, my goal is to have the ion-item use its this.status to determine the proper background color.  When I run my application, this is the html that is generated:

```
<ion-item class="item item-block item-ios" ng-style="{'background-color': item.status}">
```

Obviously, I did not intend for 'item.status' to be the background color, I was hoping for #FFFF99.

Any suggestions or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This will be difficult, because `scss` is a language that needs to be compiled to `css` before running the application. And you want to select your color in runtime. You could define your colors in a Javascript object and select it this way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you add some (S)CSS classes for your possible states like so:

```
.pending {
     background-color: #FFFF99;
}
.complete {
     background-color: #9966ff;
}
.overdue {
     background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

And then dynamically set the class of your items according to their state, something like this:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" [class]="item.status">{{item.title}}</ion-item>
```

Comment: @user9088454 What exactly isn't working? Maybe you can create a MVCE and create another question with your code...