# Ionic - How can I programmatically set the text color of an item?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

In Ionic (3), how can I programmatically set the text color of an item?

For example, clicking on a list item will change (toggle) the color of the list item.

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-content padding>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let element of elements" #listitem (click)="changeTextColor(listitem)">
        Click to change text color of {{element}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

With the code of the changeTextColor:

```
changeTextColor( listitem) {
    console.log( 'changing text color');
    listitem._color="danger";
}
```

Comment: My answer here might get you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50494863/5730444

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this seems to be a "Restyle X when Y happens"-question, I'll try to explain the steps to resolve a task like this in general. I've answered a simpler question like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50494863/5730444), which might also help to get started.

Solving this kind of problems normally includes the following steps:

1. **Define CSS classes** for each state you want to display
2. **Assign one of the defined CSS classes** to your element(s)
3. **Store the current state/CSS class**
4. **Handle changes**

---

#### Define CSS classes

So, first of all, we'll have to find the states we want to display. These often reflect states in our business logic. For the sake of demonstration, I'll take your example of only two state *danger* and *normal*. This could also be *pending*, *complete* and *overdue* (see my other answer above) or anything else.

Now we're going to define CSS classes for every state. In your case this could look something like this:

```
.normal {
  color: black;
}
.danger {
  color: red;
}
```

Of course, we could also style the `background-color` or anything else here.

If you want to reuse colors defined in `variables.scss`, you can use the [`map-get` function](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#map_get-instance_method) like so:

```
.danger {
  color: map-get($colors, danger);
}
```

---

#### Assign one of the defined CSS classes

Now we can assign our initial CSS class to the elements we want to style. This is pretty straight forward using the `class` operator:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let element of elements" [class]="normal">
        Click to change text color of {{element}}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

---

#### Store the current state/CSS class

Next we need to store our current state/CSS class, so we can handle changes to it. In your case we'll have to turn the elements we're iterating over with `*ngFor` into objects with a property to store our current CSS class (we'll call this property `state`):

```
elements = [{ text: 'hi', state: 'normal' },
  { text: 'there', state: 'normal' },
  { text: '!', state: 'normal' }];
```

If you're already using objects just add a property storing your state.

We'll have to update our HTML to reflect our changes in the code:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let element of elements" [class]="element.state">
        Click to change text color of {{element.text}}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

---

#### Handle changes

We're already setting our state/CSS class dynamically, but how to handle changes? Therefore we'll create a method with our logic:

```
changeTextColor(listitem) {
    if (listitem.state === 'normal') {
      listitem.state = 'danger';
    } else {
      listitem.state = 'normal';
    }
}
```

And use it in our HTML:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let element of elements" (click)="changeTextColor(element)" [class]="element.state">
        Click to change text color of {{element.text}}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

---

Also [see this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-jiaahb) for a runnable version of the above code.

Comment: Thank you, as indicated, a very nice answer!