# how to change pressed item background color in ion-list with Ionic3 using localstorage

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

plz help me,i want to change pressed item background color in ion-list with Ionic3 using localstorage,so the clicked items has a grey background and the non-clicked items has a white background.
this is my html code :

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let div of divs; let i = index" >
   {{ div.name }}
</ion-item>
```

and this is the array on ts file

```
divs: any[] = [
    { name: '1'},
    { name: '2'},
    { name: '3'},
    { name: '4'},
    { name: '5'},
    { name: '6'},
];
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51917772/5730444) might get you in the right direction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of `localstorage` for this.

You can use below two methods to fulfil your requirement.

1. Using `ngStyle`
2. Using `ngClass`

> Solution using `ngStyle`

- Keep boolean attribute as `isClicked` for every element in `divs` array and change it's value on click on list item and set `ngStyle` according to `isClicked`.

> Example

**TS**

```
export class ExamplePage {

  divs;

  constructor() {

    this.divs = [
        { name: '1', isClicked: false},
        { name: '2', isClicked: false},
        { name: '3', isClicked: false},
        { name: '4', isClicked: false},
        { name: '5', isClicked: false},
        { name: '6', isClicked: false},
      ];
      }

  onItemClick(div) {

      if (div.isClicked) {

        div.isClicked = false;

      } else {

        div.isClicked = true;
      }
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <ion-item
      *ngFor="let div of divs" (click)="onItemClick(div)"
      [ngStyle]="{ background: div.isClicked ? '#FF5733': '#33FF93'}">

    {{ div.name }}
  </ion-item>
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-xcho4h?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

Comment: @jack    if this answer  worked for you marked it as correct answer.